# Return all elements matching class name

Tags: javascript

`document.getElementsByClassName('big-button')[0,1,2].style.display = "inline-flex";`

I'm trying to apply that style to all/any element that matches the class name. I tried `[0,1,2]` because I just have 3 instances, but it only targets the third instance.

This does not need to work in production. Just in Chrome. It's just prototyping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you put commas between values inside square brackets, you're invoking the *comma operator*, which evaluates each item in the comma-separated list, and then evaluates to the final value in the list. Thus, your code evaluates to `[2]`, or only the third item. Generally, if you have an array-like object on the left hand side, you need to provide a *single* value in the following square brackets, like `[0]` or `[1]`.

If you want to apply that style to the first three elements of the list, you'll have to explicitly iterate over them. For example, one possible implementation is:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.big-button');
const firstThreeButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons, 0, 3);
firstThreeButtons.forEach(button => button.style.display = 'inline-flex');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are N counts of ways to achieve it.

1. make a function which will walk through array indexes and do Your stuff:

```js
function borderRed(className, elementIndexes) {
  elementIndexes.forEach(index => {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className)[index].style = "border: 1px solid red";
  });
}

borderRed('big-button', [0, 2, 4]);
```

```html
<button class="big-button">1</button>
<button class="big-button">2</button>
<button class="big-button">3</button>
<button class="big-button">4</button>
<button class="big-button">5</button>
<button class="big-button">6</button>
```

2. cache result to variable and call operation 3 times:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('big-button');

buttons[0].style = 'border: 1px solid red';
buttons[2].style = 'border: 1px solid red';
buttons[4].style = 'border: 1px solid red';
```

```html
<button class="big-button">1</button>
<button class="big-button">2</button>
<button class="big-button">3</button>
<button class="big-button">4</button>
<button class="big-button">5</button>
<button class="big-button">6</button>
```

3. using jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('.big-button').slice(0, 3).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="big-button">1</button>
<button class="big-button">2</button>
<button class="big-button">3</button>
<button class="big-button">4</button>
<button class="big-button">5</button>
<button class="big-button">6</button>
```

4. using `document.querySelector`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.big-button:nth-child(1),.big-button:nth-child(3),.big-button:nth-child(5)');

buttons.forEach(button => button.style = 'border: 1px solid red');
```

```html
<button class="big-button">1</button>
<button class="big-button">2</button>
<button class="big-button">3</button>
<button class="big-button">4</button>
<button class="big-button">5</button>
<button class="big-button">6</button>
```